# React controlled component with hardcoded value loses fast keypresses on mobile

Tags: reactjs, mobile

I have a text input with the value hardcoded to an empty string whose onChange event I'm using to populate data elsewhere. This works on Chrome and Firefox on desktop (Windows) and mobile (Android), except when typing quickly it loses some keypresses just on mobile. If I type two letters very quickly, only one onChange event will be fired. What's causing this?

Here's a minimal version to demonstrate what isn't working:

```
import React, { ChangeEvent } from 'react';

const Test: React.FC = () => {
  const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type='text' value='' onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

If I press two keys simultaneously on desktop, I see log messages for both keys. If I do so on mobile, I only see a message for one of them.

For comparison, here are two alternate components that don't lose keypresses on mobile, but don't work for the functionality I'm trying to accomplish.

Normal controlled component:

```
import React, { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react';

const Test: React.FC = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type='text' value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Uncontrolled component watching changes:

```
import React, { ChangeEvent } from 'react';

const Test: React.FC = () => {
  const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type='text' onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

I'm trying to figure out what's going on under the hood in React that's swallowing just one of the onChange events just on mobile just for a hardcoded value just when typing very quickly.